# gcloud command to list all project owner

Tags: google-cloud-platform, scripting, gcloud, identity-management

Searching for a GCP cmd to list all the active owners of a project. Have tried using the below cmd but it lists all the IAM policies. I only require project owner information.

gcloud projects get-iam-policy $PROJECT-ID

Comment: Only the owner of the current project? Or the owner of the project in a folder or an organization?

Answer (score 1):

Try:

```bash
PROJECT="[YOUR-PROJECT-ID]"

gcloud projects get-iam-policy ${PROJECT} \
--flatten="bindings" \
--filter="bindings.role=roles/owner" \
--format="value(bindings.members[])"
```

This uses `gcloud`'s `--flatten`, `--format` and `--filter`. See [this] post for a very good explanation.

It's confusing but `--filter` can only be used on lists and so `--flatten` is used to convert a single resource with a single `bindings` into multiple documents root on `bindings`.

Then it's possible to filter out the `roles` of value `roles/owner`.

Then format the result to include only the `members`.

**Note:** `members` are prefixed with the type (`user:`, `serviceAccount:` etc.). You may want to further process these.

Or:

```bash
PROJECT="[YOUR-PROJECT-ID]"

FILTER="
  .bindings[]
  |select(.role==\"roles/owner\").members"

gcloud projects get-iam-policy ${PROJECT} \
--format=json \
| jq -r "${FILTER}"
```

If you're willing to use [`jq`](https://stedolan.github.io/jq/) to process JSON. You can have `gcloud --format=json` emit JSON and then process it using `jq`.

The advantage of this approach is that you learn and use one tool (i.e. `jq`) to process JSON output from any number of commands (not just `gcloud`).

The disadvantage of this approach is that you need to use multiple tools  (`gcloud` and `jq`) instead of just one (`gcloud`).

In the case of `jq`, it's easier (!?) to write a filter that extracts the email from the member:

```bash
FILTER="
  .bindings[]
  |select(.role==\"roles/owner\").members[]
  |split(\":\")[1]"
```